# GLFW file location for new project on CodeBlocks - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl, codeblocks, glfw

I am trying to create a project using OpenGL with GLFW using CodeBlocks. The thing is that when it asks me for the GLFW location, it is not working if I put the /usr/include.. path nor the manual download of the glfw3.h .
What path should I put there to have it working on Ubuntu?

/usr/include/GLFW  -> this is the folder for the GLFW.

I also have it in downlaods.

[image]

Comment: From my experience, CB project templates are mostly useless. It's much easier to create an empty project, then add compiler flags manually.

Comment: In the future, consider adding a language tag for more exposure. Probably either C or C++.